# fetch time is taking time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, database-administration

I am running below simple query,execution time is 1sec but fetch time is 30 sec. It contains totally 100 000 records

```
SELECT id, referrer, timestamp  
FROM masterstats_innodb 
WHERE video = 1869 AND timestamp between '2011-10-01' and '2021-01-21';
```

Index is created on video and timestamp column and even range partition has been created on timestamp table. Can anything be done to fetch result faster?

Comment: if this is a performance-related question, it will be better to include the execution plan.

Comment: query execution time is fast ,only fetch time is slow.103782 row(s) returned 0.922 sec / 49.594 sec

Comment: huh usually a slow fetch indicate the server deliver the data back to you is slow, and in this case 100k rows( not sure how big those data actually is... ) doesn't seem to be a humongous amount of data to have this slow delivery.

Comment: err... maybe check your innodb_buffer_pool_size ?

Comment: yes, it is 2GB pool size

Comment: If your columns are really big, then it takes longer to return them.  Similarly, if the available network bandwidth is very small, then it will take a long time.

Comment: You meant to say data present in column? @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Plan A:  `INDEX(video, timestamp)`

Plan B - slightly better because of being "covering":

```
INDEX(video, timestamp, referrer, id)
```

`PARTITIONing` will not help the performance of this query any more than indexing.

You say "it" contains 100K rows -- are you referring to the table?  Or the just the number of rows returned.  If 'table', then the index will help.  If the 'resultset', then you are constrained by having to send so many rows.  What will the client do with 100K rows??  Can the server condense the data (eg summarize it in some way)?

Comment: number of rows returned 100K rows.This query is using on website to display the stats report  with time range value.

Comment: @AnilMoolya - And you display all 100K rows?  Or paginate them?  Or summarize them?  There are techniques for returning only the amount of data that will actually be displayed; we can discuss them.